# How to convert ISO8601 format into milliseconds?

Tags: java, android, datetime

I'm pretty surprised that I haven't yet found a really easy way considering how often ISO8601 is used in JSON.

Basically, I'm taking a string that looks like this: `2014-10-23T00:35:14.800Z` and converting it into something like `50 minutes ago`.

First, I have to change `2014-10-23T00:35:14.800Z`to `2014-10-23'T'00:35:14.800Z`, then I need to convert it to milliseconds, then it is easy.

My current code:

```
private void setTimestamp(String timeCreated) {
    int indexOfT = timeCreated.indexOf('T');

    String properFormat = new StringBuilder(timeCreated).insert(indexOfT + 1, "'")
                                                        .insert(indexOfT, "'")
                                                        .toString();

    timeStamp = (String) DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(Long.parseLong(properFormat),
                                  System.currentTimeMillis(), 
                                  DateUtils.SECONDS_IN_MILLIS);
}
```

The culprit is `Long.parseLong(properFormat)`. I need to convert `properFormat` into milliseconds.

Comment: See [Joda Time](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/cal_iso.html).

Comment: If you use Java 8, you may find [this discussion](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/225343/why-are-the-java-8-java-time-classes-missing-a-getmillis-method) interesting.

Comment: Please let me know why you downvoted this.

Comment: @David I'm not the downvoter. But I suspect the downvoting may be due to this topic being handled in many hundreds of questions and answers on StackOverflow.

Comment: @PM77-1 No Java 8 nor java.time in Android.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

## tl;dr

```
Instant.parse( "2014-10-23T00:35:14.800Z" )
       .toEpochMilli()
```

## One-Liner In java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These new classes supplant the old date-time classes bundled with the earliest versions of Java such as java.util.Date/.Calendar. See [Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). The java.time classes also supplant the highly successful [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library, being built by some of the same folks including being led by the same [Stephen Colbourne](https://stackoverflow.com/users/38896/jodastephen).

An [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html) is a moment on the timeline in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time) with a resolution of [nanoseconds](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nanosecond). You can [ask it for a count of milliseconds](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toEpochMilli--) from its [epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Epoch_(reference_date)) (first moment of 1970 in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time)). But remember that an `Instant` may have additional data, nanoseconds being finer than milliseconds. So you **may be losing data** in that tiny fraction of a fraction of a second.

The java.time classes use standard ISO 8601 formats when parsing/generating strings. No need to specify a formatting pattern. The `Instant` class can [directly parse](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#parse-java.lang.CharSequence-) a string.

```
Instant.parse( "2014-10-23T00:35:14.800Z" )
```

You can convert that to a count of milliseconds since the epoch of first moment of 1970 in UTC by calling `toEpochMilli`

Be aware of possible data loss as the `Instant` class can hold nanoseconds. So extracting milliseconds will be truncating any microseconds or nanoseconds in any fractional second. Your example string has only three digits in the fractional second, so that is only milliseconds. But six or nine digits of decimal fraction would be truncated to three when converted to a count of milliseconds.

```
long millisFromEpoch = Instant.parse( "2014-10-23T00:35:14.800Z" ).toEpochMilli();
```

To get elapsed time in terms of hours-minutes-seconds, use the [`Duration`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html) class. Feed its [`between`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Duration.html#between-java.time.temporal.Temporal-java.time.temporal.Temporal-) method a pair of moments in time.

```
Duration duration = Duration.between( Instant.parse( "2014-10-23T00:35:14.800Z" ) , Instant.now() );
```

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

You may exchange *java.time* objects directly with your database. Use a [JDBC driver](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JDBC_driver) compliant with [JDBC 4.2](http://openjdk.java.net/jeps/170) or later. No need for strings, no need for `java.sql.*` classes.

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), [**Java SE 10**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_10), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android (<26), the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

[image: Table of which java.time library to use with which version of Java or Android]

---

## One-Liner In Joda-Time

**UPDATE:** The Joda-Time project is in maintenance mode, with the team advising migration to the java.time classes.

With the [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) 2.5 library:

```
long millisSinceEpoch = new DateTime( "2014-10-23T00:35:14.800Z" ).getMillis();
```

Joda-Time parses and generates [ISO 8601](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601) strings by default. Joda-Time works in Android. The java.util.Date/.Calendar classes are notoriously troublesome, confusing, and flawed. Avoid them.

Comment: I think I'll definitely use this. Seems like a one-liner tailor-made for my dates.

Comment: Down-voter: Please leave a criticism along with your vote, especially on an accepted Answer.

Comment: `Instant` is available on Android since API 26 only

Comment: @rightaway717 Most of the functionality of *java.time* built into Java 8 is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in the *ThreeTen-Backport* project, and further adapted for early Android in *ThreeTenABP*.

Comment: @rightaway717 **Update** The latest tooling for Android makes must of the functionality of *java.time* available to earlier versions of Android via "API desugaring". So no need to add a library.

Answer (score 6):

So, turns out the answer was simpler than I would have imagined.

```
private void setTimestamp(String timeCreated) {
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSSZ");
    try {
        Date timeCreatedDate = dateFormat.parse(timeCreated);
        timeStamp = (String) DateUtils.getRelativeTimeSpanString(timeCreatedDate.getTime(),
                                  System.currentTimeMillis(), 
                                  DateUtils.SECONDS_IN_MILLIS);
    } catch ( ParseException e) {}
}
```

That'll work.