# How do I convert timestamps in ISO 8601 format with an offset-from-UTC to EpochMilli in Java/Scala

Tags: java, scala

I have strings in ISO 8601 format with timezone offset. They are in the format “2017-05-21T20:37:08.021-05:00”. I want to convert to EpochMilli in Java/Scala.

Instant.parse( "2017-05-21T20:37:08.021-05:00" )
      .toEpochMilli()

gives me the error
java.time.format.DateTimeParseException: Text '2017-05-21T20:37:08.021-05:00' could not be parsed at index 23

Comment: since you have a timezone use OffsetDateTime like in `OffsetDateTime.parse( "2017-05-21T20:37:08.021-05:00" ) .toInstant() .toEpochMilli()`

Comment: Very similar to: [*How to convert ISO8601 format into milliseconds?*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26519867/642706)

Comment: **Dear down-voters,** please leave a criticism along with your vote. If you believe this to be a duplicate, bother to find the duplicate. I tried and failed, finding only questions like this for UTC, not for an offset-from-UTC.

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because `Instant` expects the input to be in [UTC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coordinated_Universal_Time). But you have a [offset](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UTC_offset) five hours behind UTC (`-05:00`), not at UTC (offset of zero).

Use [`OffsetDateTime`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/OffsetDateTime.html) to parse your string. Then adjust into UTC by extracting an [`Instant`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html).

```
OffsetDateTime odt = OffsetDateTime.parse("2017-05-21T20:37:08.021-05:00");
Instant i = odt.toInstant();
long millis = i.toEpochMilli();

System.out.println(i);
System.out.println(millis);
```

Will print:

```
2017-05-22T01:37:08.021Z
1495417028021
```

Comment: Your code is correct, but those first two sentences are incorrect and nonsensical. The input string *is* in standard ISO 8601 format. And ISO 8601 *does* allow for milliseconds as a fractional second. Indeed, ISO 8601 allows for *any* granularity of resolution in the fractional second. Fix those two sentences, and then let the up-votes roll in.

Comment: `Instant` is in UTC, always in UTC, by definition. So it only accepts inputs with an offset-from-UTC of zero, that is, UTC itself. The `Z` on the end means UTC, pronounced "Zulu". The input string here has `-05:00` for an offset-from-UTC of five hours behind UTC. So we must parse that as a `OffsetDateTime`. Then adjust to UTC, as you did, by extracting an `Instant`.

Comment: I removed your word "timezone" as an offset is *not* a time zone. An offset-from-UTC is merely a number of hours, minutes, and seconds. Nothing more, nothing less. A time zone is much more. A time zone is a history of past, present, and future changes to the offset used by the people of a particular region. A [time zone has a name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_tz_database_time_zones) in `Continent/Region` format.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you added a little bit more info than was needed.

Take a look at this - https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/Instant.html#toEpochMilli--

notice how you have a `-05:00` ? Notice the `-` sign. That was the 23rd character and that was more than what was asked for. They only want the date followed by the time, not time zone. Remember, timezone has no bearing on epoch because epoch assumes you are using the -0:00 timezone (greenwich england).

EDIT - basically, find the time you want, put it in greenwich time, then run it through the method again, but without the timezone as part of your parameter.

Alternatively, if the current time you have is correct (which it likely isn't, considering the `-05:00`), then just get rid of the `-05:00`.